# Send mail on condition (Only if user fills specific rows)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to code a VBA such that the mail can be sent only if the user fills in details in rows. If not, an alert showing "Cannot send update. Fill the details completely" should pop up on the users screen.

Eg: The user has to fil Columns "A to J" and "M". If not they cannot send mail and pop up should ask them to enter it.

I have the following code as below,

```
Sub MAIL()
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = "abc@gmail.com"

EmailItem.Subject = " "
EmailItem.HTMLBody = ""
Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source

EmailItem.Send

End Sub
```

Please help me provide alerts to users. I am completely new to this.

Comment: `to fil Columns "A to J" and "M"` is a little foggy... How this  to be appreciated? Aren't already be filled anything, like headers or something else? You should better describe this aspect, than only copying a code from internet... If only a cell is filled in all the mentioned columns, should it be considered that the check has been done and it passes?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I want the user to fill in the details under column headers which ranges from A to J and M , (which is asterisk)  and then only they can send mail if not the pop up must ask them to fill it.


Once the user fills the columns , they can click send mail.

Comment: What does "details under column headers" mean? A code cannot think as a humam being... If all mentioned columns contain more than a record (header), should the mail be sent? At least, place  relevant pictures for both situations if not able to explain in words...

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next function. It will check if **at least a cell is filled in all columns of the range ("A:J, M:M")**. In such a case it returns `True`. Otherwise, it send a relevant message and returns false, stopping the mail sending:

```
Function checkIfOK() As Boolean
   Dim rng As Range, ar As Range, i As Long

   Set rng = Range("A:J,M:M")
   For Each ar In rng.Areas
        For i = 1 To ar.Columns.count
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ar.Columns(i)) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "Column " & Split(ar.Columns(i).cells(1).Address, "$")(1) & " is empty..."
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
   Next ar
   checkIfOK = True
End Function
```

You have to use it in your code in the next way:

```
Sub MAIL()
 If Not checkIfOK Then Exit Sub 'it stop the code here if the function returns False
 
 Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application, Source As String
 Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

 Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 EmailItem.To = "abc@gmail.com"

 EmailItem.Subject = " "
 EmailItem.HtmlBody = ""
 Source = ThisWorkbook.fullName
 EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source

 EmailItem.Send
End Sub
```

The function has been built on the above mentioned assumption. I asked you in my comment **"How this to be appreciated?"** and you did not answer anything...

Comment: I just checked ur answer. It isn't working for me. Mail is directly being sent without user filling the required columns.

Comment: I adapted the function to pass the check only if more than a header exist in each column. I did it for the case you answer the clarification question after many hours...